# XP gives Error 1825 when trying to connect to my web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I've been creating a an application with C# using W2k8+IIS7/SQLExpress 2008/Web Service/Windows Client. I'll be very upfront in that I'm learning how to setup the SQL and IIS and the security for it all. I don't need tight SSL security or any of that, since this is an intranet page inside my company. I do know I setup SQL and IIS to use NTAUTH_SERVICE and that SQL is in mixed mode.

Everything is working on Vista and Win7, except on Windows XPSP3 x86 which will not talk to the service. The purpose of the windows client is to gather the machine specs via WMI and then send it to the web service. Even when I install VS 2008 SP1 on the machine to do some remote debugging (Attach to Process on my server), I get this Error Code 1825:

***Windows Error Message 1825: 'RPC_S_SEC_PKG_ERROR'
A security package specific error occurred.***

Does anyone have an ideas on how to fix this? Or what's causing it? Much appreciated =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be just a work-around or gremlins ...or the fix itself -- Changing the 'Connection Timeout' from the default 2mins to 8mins in the website's IIS settings fixed the whole dang thing.